# How to intrpret Tcl "list as string" as list?

Tags: string, list, tcl

By some unknown reason the variable `result` in the following line of code

```
set result [[$sqlCmd execute] allrows -as lists]
```

gets string which looks like list: `{2 3 4 5}`

If I write `puts "result $result => [llength $result]"` it prints `{2 3 4 5} => 1`

if I write `puts [list $result]`, it prints `{{2 3 4 5}}`, what is correct because `list` creates list from one string.
Is there any way to convert this string to what it expected to be - list - without any string processing steps like deletion of braces and splitting string to list by `split` function? I suggest it must be some interpretation but I'm unable to find nice solutition.

Comment: Not a TCL expert, but that looks like your SQL command is giving you a length-1 list whose 1 element is another list. If the command had selected two rows, it would have given you a length-2 list whose elements were individual lists representing individual rows.

Comment: @user2357112 I'm not sure I understand what do you mean. It looks good suggestion that list of length-1 becomes notlist. But how could it happen?And being executed in SQL Server console, request returns exactly one row of data, what is expected. So, why, actually, should it return list of some different length. Please explain, what do you mean.

Comment: "list of length-1 becomes notlist" - what? No, it's still a list. Why do you think it's not?

Comment: @user2357112 because llength returns 1 while it contains 4 elements

Comment: No, the list contains *1* element. The 1 element is another list containing 4 elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`allrows` is giving you a list of lists, each sublist representing a row. There is 1 row in this list, `2 3 4 5`, so the length is 1. You can index or iterate over the list the usual ways to access its one element.

```
# If you're assuming there will only be one row
set only_row [lindex $result 0]

# Or if you want to iterate over all rows
foreach row $result {
    do whatever with $row
}
```

Comment: This row should be list. But it is not.

Comment: @OlegG: It *is* a list.

Comment: Yes. The code [lindex $result 0 0] returns 2. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

The `allrows` method always returns a list, one per row (even when there's only a single row returned). When the `-as lists` option is passed in, each element of that list is itself a list representing the columns in that row.

Thus, to iterate over the columns of that row, you'd do:

```
set result [[$sqlCmd execute] allrows -as lists]  
set rowresult [lindex $result 0]
foreach col $rowresult {
    puts "I've got a '$col'"
}
```

You're usually recommended to use the default that represents rows as dictionaries indexed by column name, as that has a better representation of SQL `NULL`s (i.e., the column is absent then instead of being the driver-designated null value, which is often and ambiguously the empty string).

Comment: Thanks fo your advice. Unfortunatelly it is not my case.